NJsonSchema additional properties generated schema uses oneOf validation
When NJsonSchema generates a json schema from a C# type containing a property decorated with the JsonExtensionDataAttribute attribute, the resulting json schema sets additional properties as
    "additionalProperties": {
        "oneOf": [
          {},
          {
            "type": "null"
          }
        ]
      }

This fails schema validation when I have a mix of string and null additional property values in my source json data. Here is a step by step example
I have a generated C# model
namespace MyNamespace
{
#pragma warning disable // Disable all warnings

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "11.0.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Model
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("id", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        private System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> _additionalProperties;

        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData]
        public System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalProperties
        {
            get { return _additionalProperties ?? (_additionalProperties = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>()); }
            set { _additionalProperties = value; }
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "11.0.2.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Example
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("data", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Always)]
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Required]
        public Model Data { get; set; } = new Model();
    }
}

I then generate a json schema based on this model using the following C#
var schema = JsonSchema.FromType<Example>();
var generatedSchema = schema.ToJson();

Which results in the following schema
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Example",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "required": [
    "Data"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "Data": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Model"
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Model": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": {
        "oneOf": [
          {},
          {
            "type": "null"
          }
        ]
      },
      "required": [
        "Id"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Id": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "AdditionalProperties": {
          "type": [
            "null",
            "object"
          ],
          "additionalProperties": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

We use the above to validate json data that contains additional properties that may be a string or null, for example
{
    "Data": {
        "Id": "82829d29",
        "SomeAdditionalProperty": "text",
        "SomeOtherAdditionalProperty": null
    }
}

Schema validation fails with the following message
JSON is valid against more than one schema from 'oneOf'. Valid schema indexes: 0, 1.
Path: #/definitions/Model/additionalProperties/oneOf
Is this by design? Can I not have a combination of string and null additional properties?

You can do type: ["string", "null"] but using "oneOf": [{}, {"type": "null"}] fails because {} is basically the same as any, including type: null.  a oneOf cannot pass validation if more than one subschema passes validation.  If you were to update to anyOf, it will pass.

@JeremyFiel, yes, I understand why the schema validation fails. My question is, why does NJsonSchema generate that schema for additional properties?
